# Get the value of array to use in sort?

Tags: c++

I need to get the result from K (number of students) but in case 2 ... program fills up all 30 places in the array with (if K=2) two number and other 28 are some kind of 38392839238 .. .some thing like that, here is my code:

```
int main()
  {
int i,n,k;
unsigned int m[30], a[30], b[30];
int ch=0, nech=0;
cout<<"Number of students (max30)";cin>>k;
for(i=0; i<k; ++i)
{
    cout<<i+1<<". Student number: ";
    do
    {
        cin>>m[i];
    }
    while(!(m[i]>=1e7 && m[i]<1e8));
    if(m[i]%2==0)
    {
        a[ch]=m[i]; ch++;
    }
    else 
    {
        b[nech]=m[i]; nech++;
    }
}
cout<<endl;
cout<<"\nAll numbers: "<<endl;
for(i=0; i<k; ++i)
    cout<<m[i]<<"\t";
    loop:
cout<<endl;
cout<<"\nChoose 1 to see Even and Odd numbers: ";
cout<<"\nChoose 2 to see ascending order: ";
cout<<"\nChoose 3 to exit: ";
cout<<"\nEnter Your choise: "; cin>>n;
switch(n)
{

case 2:
    {
        {
        int e=sizeof(m) / sizeof(m[0]);
        sort(m,m+e);
        for(i=0;i<e;++i)
            cout<<"\n"<<m[i]<<' ';
        }
    }
    goto loop;

}
 }
```

This program wants to enter the number of students in class, after that it wants to enter their number in class and in CASE 2 i it need to make them in ascending order. For example:
Number of students in class: 2
 1. Student number: 12345678
 2. Student number: 55555555

and when you hit 2 for case2 it needs to make their ascending order, so result must be:
12345678
55555555
(from min to max).
My program makes it but on the other 28 places (my array must be max 30) it puts another number = 3435973836

Comment: Could you please make the introduction to your code clearer? Right now one needs to read the entire code to even understand what this is about. Also, your minimal example could probably be smaller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that you see has to do with reading from the elements of the arrays that have not been initialized, and therefore containing garbage values.

Your first loop assign values to the top `k` elements, yet inside the `case '2'` you have a loop that sorts and outputs the entire array. This is undefined behavior, because you are reading from unassigned elements of the array.

Using `k` instead of `e` would fix this problem:

```
sort(m, m+k);
for(i=0;i<k;++i)
    cout<<"\n"<<m[i]<<' ';
}
```

Comment: Good Job ! Thank you dasblinkenlight :)